# Python handler to check condition

Tags: python, python-decorators

I try to control the evaluating of functions with the help of decorators.
So I create an instance of `MyClass` and then evaluate functions on condition the `mode` property suits.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mode = None

    def mode_handler(self, mode):
        def wrap(func):
            def inner(*args, **kwargs):
                if mode == self.mode:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    pass
            return inner
        return wrap

a = MyClass()


@a.mode_handler(mode='repeat')
def print_args(*args):
    print(args)


@a.mode_handler(mode='nuff_saif')
def nuff_said():
    print('NUFF SAID')

# 1
a.mode = 'nuff_said'
print_args(1, 2, 3)
nuff_said()

# 2
a.mode = 'repeat'
print_args(4, 5, 6)
nuff_said()

# 3
a.mode = 'something_else'
print_args(7, 8, 9)
nuff_said()
```

I expected to get

```
NUFF SAID
(4, 5, 6)
```

as at block 1 `mode=='nuff_said'` and at block 2 `mode=='repeat'`.

I got

```
(4, 5, 6)
```

instead. How should I improve my code?

Comment: Interesting use of decorators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your mode handler itself:

```
@a.mode_handler(mode='repeat')
def print_args(*args):
    print(args)


@a.mode_handler(mode='nuff_saif') ### Here it is "nuff_saif"
def nuff_said():
    print('NUFF SAID')

# 1
a.mode = 'nuff_said' ### Here it is "nuff_said"
print_args(1, 2, 3)
nuff_said()

# 2
a.mode = 'repeat'
print_args(4, 5, 6)
nuff_said()
```

You can edit your code, and it should work then. Cheers.

Comment: I'm assuming here that you gave the exact code that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have a typo in your code. The decorator of `nuff_said` function is with mode nuff_sai**f** but you change the mode of the instance before calling the function to nuff_sai**d**.